# twitter bootstrap modal not posting via php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a complete noob that has hit a road block. I'm using twitter bootstrap and am attempting to POST a form modal to mysql server via php. Here is my code:

HTML (index.html):

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="ModalLabel">****</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="modal-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" action="submitform.php" data-remote="true" >
      <p>Give us your email, and we'll send you an invitation</p>
      <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="reqInput" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="reqInput" placeholder="Full Name">
    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" class="reqInput" placeholder="Company">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="reqInput" placeholder="Title">
      </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <a id="modal-form-submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href"#">Submit</a>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

PHP (submitform.php):

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="***"; // Mysql username 
$password="***"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="users"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="userRequests"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$name=$_POST['name']; 
$company=$_POST['company'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$title=$_POST['title'];

if(strlen($name) > 1 && strpos($email, "@")){

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$name = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($name));
$company = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($company));
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($email));
$title = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($title));

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (FullName, Company, Email, Title) VALUES ('$name', '$company', '$email', '$title')";

exit;
}
?>
```

I'm checking Charles and oddly I don't even see a POST sent for ~45 seconds until I get a local command error. As such, I'm a loss on how to proceed. I'm sure I'm missing a couple of things. Any advice is appreciated.

P.S. I know the SQL database is working since it connects to the old php site I'm looking to replace. Fields are text, etc. The issue is with my code above.

Comment: [Get firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) this will help you debug these issues in the future.

Comment: Please use PDO if you can.

Comment: I have never written any PDO. I think my issue is the form will not even POST. But I'm at a loss as to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the closing `}` for your `if(strlen(....`

Updated:

HTML

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="ModalLabel">****</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="modal-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" action="submitform.php" data-remote="true" >
      <p>Give us your email, and we'll send you an invitation</p>
      <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="reqInput" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="reqInput" placeholder="Full Name">
    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" class="reqInput" placeholder="Company">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="reqInput" placeholder="Title">
      </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <input id="modal-form-submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href"#" value="Submit"/>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

You can't have an `<a>` tag have an input type.  This should post your code.  Why do you have `exit;` on your PHP file?

Comment: There's a lot of code that I'm sure we're not seeing, which is okay.  But can you `print_r($_POST);` and get back the Posted information before doing your `if` statement?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that it doesn't look like you're actually `<submit>`ing the form

Comment: That could be completely possible. I edited the code slightly but can you give me a hint as to where you think the issue is (if it still exists); related to the html button submit?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the submit button, instead of

```
<a id="modal-form-submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href"#">Submit</a>
```

Use

```
<input type="submit" id="modal-form-submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
```